# SQL Server debugging stored procedure using old version of code

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server, and I'm trying to debug it using SSMS. Here's my process:

1. Change the stored procedure and execute
2. Run the stored procedure in debug mode to observe the effects of my change - this opens a new tab in SSMS for debugging
3. Finish the debug session, change the stored procedure and re-execute

It would appear that if I don't close the tab created in step 2 then the debugger uses the previous version of the stored procedure. Is this a known issue with debugging in SSMS and if so, is there a workaround or fix for it?

Comment: Not really an answer, but I don't debug SPs, Copy the guts of it into a window, debug that.

Comment: Yes - I usually do that myself.  Which may be why this is the first time I've encountered this strange phenomenon.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is some sort of lock on the sp itself. Quick way to find out might be to try and drop it from another session. Also see waht difference it makes if you open up the query window with the current connection or a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

Use 'DBCC FREEPROCCACHE' to clear the procedure cache.

Freeing the procedure cache would cause, for example, an ad-hoc SQL statement to be recompiled rather than reused from the cache. If observing through SQL Profiler, one can watch the Cache Remove events occur as DBCC FREEPROCCACHE goes to work. DBCC FREEPROCCACHE will invalidate all stored procedure plans that the optimizer has cached in memory and force SQL Server to compile new plans the next time those procedures are run.

-- All credit to--> [Dave Pinal on Cache](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/23/sql-server-stored-procedure-clean-cache-and-clean-buffer/)
Otherwise you can

> Drop proc stpMyModifiedProcedure
>
> Create proc stpMyModifiedProcedure

This will work also... altering will alter sproc, but not in the cache... droppling will update the cache.